# How to call original function when it's shadowed by binding?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have such situation:

```
 (defn a []
   (do-something))

 (defn b []
   (let [original (a)]
      (modify-original)))

 (defn c []
   (binding a b)
     (a))
```

How can I "break binding" and call `a` in `b`? I thought that closures can handle such situation so I wrote something similiar to this but it didn't work:

```
 (defn c []
   (let [original-a a
         b (fn [] 
             (let [original (original-a)]
               (modify-original)))]
     (b)))
```

Oh, I almost forgot: the code is much more complicated because `c` doesn't directly call `b`. It's called in it's subfunction which I cannot change. This is why I can't use something like:

`(defn ^:dynamic state [] (something))`

Comment: To get this to work, "a" should be declared as dynamic, I think. If you really want to call the root value of "a", then why can't you just copy the value of a to another var before the binding form, then call that instead. Or am I miss understanding your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want always use the original value of `a` in function `b` as you mentioned you can "grab" the original `a` into environment of function `b` (closure):

```
(defn ^:dynamic a []
  (do-something))

(def b (let [a a]
         (fn []
           (let [original (a)]
             (modify-original)))))

(defn c []
  (binding [a b]
    (a)))
```

**Update**. Or

```
(let [a a] (defn b []
             (let [original (a)]
               (modify-original))))
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I cannot change `a`? It's a library function.

Comment: @AdamSznajder I've not changed `a`. Or do you mean `^:dynamic` part? Without this you can't `bind` new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can **use java threads to "see through" bindings** by creating and then grabbing the value of the var from a thread on which it is not bound, and leaving it in a var/atom/ref/etc to be found by the code on the thread for which it is bound:

```
user> (defn c [] 
        (let [tmp-atom (atom nil) 
              original-a (do (doto (Thread. #(reset! tmp-atom a)) .start .join) 
                             @tmp-atom)] 
          {:local-a a :original-a original-a}))
user> (c)
{:local-a 4, :original-a 4}
user> (binding [a 7] (c))
{:local-a 7, :original-a 4}
```

---

Or for a smaller example, first define a bit of shared state and a var to bind

```
user> (def result (atom ""))
#'user/result
user> (def ^:dynamic a 4)
#'user/a
```

on an a thread without the bindings capture the a, which will get the root value of a:

```
user> (binding [a 5] (.start (Thread. #(reset! result  (str "a was " a)))))
#<Thread Thread[Thread-77,5,main]>
user> result
#<Atom@7c75031f: "a was 4">
```

then compare that to running the same code without the thread where the bound value of a is used:

```
user> (binding [a 5] (reset! result  (str "a was " a)))
"a was 5" 
user> result
#<Atom@7c75031f: "a was 5">
user>
```

Most (all?) the normal Clojure concurrency tools are careful to push bindings to new threads to prevent situations like this

---

putting this together: